# How to run query on Hive table with JsonSerDe using Spark interpreter in Zeppelin / HDP 2.4?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Not able to run hive query using spark Interpreter in Zeppelin.

I am able to load hive context. Hive table is using `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe` . But query always returning: `classNotFoundException org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe`.

i added `spark.executor.extraClassPath` and `spark.driver.extraClassPath` in spark configuration.

i tried copying jar in `/interpreter/spark/dep` folder as well but no luck.

I added this in Zeppelin Interpreter configuration as well. I am stuck , please help me.

StackTrace:::

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.TableDesc.getDeserializerClass(TableDesc.java:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScan.addColumnMetadataToConf(HiveTableScan.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScan.<init>(HiveTableScan.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveStrategies$HiveTableScans$$anonfun$3.apply(HiveStrategies.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveStrategies$HiveTableScans$$anonfun$3.apply(HiveStrategies.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanner.pruneFilterProject(SparkPlanner.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveStrategies$HiveTableScans$.apply(HiveStrategies.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.planLater(QueryPlanner.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies$Aggregation$.apply(SparkStrategies.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.planLater(QueryPlanner.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies$BasicOperators$.apply(SparkStrategies.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1413)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1495)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:363)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:37)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
    at <init>(<console>:51)
    at .<init>(<console>:55)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:709)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:673)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:666)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.interpret(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:57)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:295)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:171)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.TableDesc.getDeserializerClass(TableDesc.java:71)
```

Comment: Can you please include the entire stack trace (to make the question more complete)?

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy `hive/lib/hive-hcatalog-core-xxx.jar` to `spark/jars/`

Comment: Using --packages submit arg would work better in a cluster environment